# Getting a JSON Left side Value

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to get the numbers "10449479", "10449480" , "10449481".

```
{
"xyz": {
"10449479": {
  "a": "22",
  "b": "33",
  "c": " - "
},
"10449480": {
  "a": "44",
  "b": "55",
  "c": " - "
  },
"10449481": {
  "a": "66",
  "b": "77",
  "c": " - "
 }}}
```

I need to get the keys() because they are unknown . How can I get these numbers. Please help.

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {//From Volley

    try {
        JSONObject jarray = response.getJSONObject("xyz");

        Iterator<String> iter = jarray.keys();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = iter.next();
            try {
                Object value = jarray.get(key);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // Something went wrong!
            }
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    }

}
```

I can only get the nested value inside each keys like

```
{
  "a": "22",
  "b": "33",
  "c": " - "
}
//and other 2
```

How can I get the left side keys. Thank you.

Comment: Do the same thing for that object too. Get the keys again and then values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If keys are dynamic you can iterate over using `jsonobj.keys()`

```
JSONObject JSONObj = new JSONObject(your_json_string);

// get all keys from json object
Iterator<String> iterator = JSONObj.keys();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterator.next();
    Log.i("TAG","key:"+key +"--Value::"+JSONObj.optString(key);
}
```

Comment: Exactly it is , I am on the wrong ways with hash keys.